# PHP code not running without session regeneration at the top of the file

Tags: php, session

Basically none of my scripts work without a session regeneration check at the top of the file, this is very strange because I've never had this issue before and I have no idea why it would force me to run this code. Below is my logout, then below that is what I have to put at the top of every single file that touches the sessions in order to make it work. Any ideas on what is wrong?

Logout:

```
require_once("../Core/Core.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']))
    Core::ThrowError(13,"",1);

session_destroy();
header("Location: " . Core::$url);
```

Required to make it work: (Also I'm putting this on every page that the user views (so no things like login script page) )

```
<?
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['started']))
    {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['started'] = true;
    }
?>
```

Update 1:

After adding session_start() above where I add data to variables I'm now able to put data into the session (Although the session was already started because it's started before you even view the login page) but when I call session_destroy() it returns false as if the session doesn't exist, but then I put session_start() above the session_destroy() and it works fine! This is really dumb whatever it is... Please help.

Update 2:

It appears I can only access session data if I put session_start() before trying to access it even if the session is already stated.

Comment: did you change `session_auto_start` or related settings recently?

Comment: No i haven't changed any settings

Comment: Write more code to test I suppose.  Maybe use `session_id` in there.  Check return values, anything returning false?  Nothing obviously wrong that I can see and it is not as if PHP sessions are 'buggy'.  Need to debug the code more.

Comment: I have lots of different functions, none of them work without this at the top of the script :/

Comment: Just added an update, might help out

Comment: in case you were confused, based on your updates, you always have to do session_start() on any file that will touch your session. that is normal. It also needs to go first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to fix it, I didn't know that "To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser." so to fix it I put session_start() in the core which is required by everything so everything would call it before trying to access the sessions.